# Can't pass values in UIStoryBoard segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I need to send bool value to Second viewController based on some condition.
but in Second ViewController the value of bool variable is always false.
This is First ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func moveTo(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Move2", sender: self)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "Move2"
    {
        let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
        secondVC?.second = true

    }
}
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

The SecondViewController code is

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
var second = Bool()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(second)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

But this Value of second variable is false.

Whats wrong in my code. need help. TIA..

EDIT : In both ViewController i have navigation controller. That's problem. SecondVC is SecondViewController's navigation controller, so that i can't pass data to that secondVC.

Comment: Did you set the segue identifier in Storyboard? Click the segue arrow and in the identify inspector set the segue identifier as `Move2`

Comment: Make sure the `class` of your `SecondViewController` has been set in the Storyboard.

Comment: ya.. set as "Move2"

Comment: @vacawama that's also done

Comment: keep a break point at *secondVC?.second = true* line. and debug is compiler stops here.

Comment: Stick a print under `secondVC?.second = true` to check that `secondVC` is not nil and in fact held this assignment.

Comment: change `second = Bool() to second: Bool = false`

Comment: Declare this variable as optional
 

`var second:Bool!`

Comment: @bauerMusic "secondVC?.second" it is nil

Comment: Well there you go. That's you issue. This means, `secondVC` is nil. That means, the VC you're getting is not what you think. Try to see it in the debugger

Comment: @RajeshKumarR now its print as nil

Comment: So value isnt passed from previous view controller. Did you use breakpoints in prepareforsegue method?

Comment: Make sure secondVC object is created and not nil

Comment: The segue is working. It seems that the ViewController is not `SecondViewController` class.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR secondVC is nil. the object not created.

Comment: Try: `print(String(describing: segue.destination))` See what class is the VC you're getting.

Comment: print(segue.destination) and check destination view controller class name

Comment: in both viewcontroller it contains Navigation Controller. I removed navigation Controller in second VC. now its working fine.. is that problem?

Comment: Have you drag your segue from ViewController or from Button.

Comment: @KaziAbdullahAlMamun from view controller

Comment: Then it should work, maybe problem was with navController what you mentioned above comment.

Comment: Check the duplicate for how to pass data through a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Storyboard and select SecondViewController (the yellow circle on the top left.  Go to identity inspector and select SecondViewController from the Class drop down.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: in both viewcontroller it contains Navigation Controller. I removed navigation Controller in second VC. now its working fine.. is that problem?

Comment: If the SecondViewController was embedded in a Navigation Controller it would cause an issue.  Typically your First VC is embedded and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep things simple and clean :

**FirstVC :**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "Move2"
        {
            let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
            secondVC.second = true

        }
    }
```

**SecondVC :**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var second: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(second)
    }  
}
```

Just tested this myself. `true` is printed.

Comment: `secondVC?.second = true` - Is optional

Comment: How about `if let secondVC = ...`, `secondVC` is an optional.

Comment: @Scriptable : I don't see any need for optional.

Comment: `let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController` as? creates optional

Comment: You can change `as?` to `as!` which is a perfectly valid coding decision.  You'd want it to crash if you didn't have the segue wired to the correct VC type.

Comment: @Scriptable : Have you tried that ? There is **no** need of taking that optional in secondVC?.second = true

Comment: @vacawama I have to disagree, allowing a crash is not a valid coding decision

Comment: @Scriptable, not having your segue wired to the correct type is a programming error not a runtime error.  It's the same as not wiring up an outlet.  You want that to crash so that you find the problem.

Comment: @Nitish its not a big deal, just trying to help improve your answer. `let vc = SecondViewController()
let secondVC = vc as? SecondViewController
print(secondVC)` prints an optional. xcode autocorrects `secondVC.second = true` to `secondVC?.second = true` try it

Comment: You cannot have `as?` casting returning a non optional.

Comment: in both viewcontroller it contains Navigation Controller. I removed navigation Controller in second VC. now its working fine.. is that problem?

Comment: @VimalkumarN.M. No it shouldn't cause any issues unless you need a nav controller there

Comment: @Nitish @Scriptable what is the differences between `var myBool = Bool()` and `var myBool = false` both are initialized with false boolean value.

Comment: @Scriptable, if he has used `as!`, it would have crashed saying `UINavigationController` couldn't be cast as `SecondViewController` and we would have solved this bug in 30 seconds.

Comment: @KaziAbdullahAlMamun nothing, myBool: Bool() is invalid though. vacamama agreed we would of got to the issue quicker. I use Swiftlint and validate my code style to that. https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Rules.md#force-unwrapping